# How to open secure site with Curl

Tags: linux, apache, curl

Recently we have to update the SSLProtocol and the SSLCipher on some apaches we were using on the office.

FROM:
`SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH`

TO:
`SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AES:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH:!EXP:!SRP:!DSS:!LOW:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1`

All the testing was done using curl command. But after the change curl starting giving errors.

`curl -v https://server1:4034/pages/Status.jsp --trace-ascii /dev/stdout`
`Warning: --trace-ascii overrides an earlier trace/verbose option`
`== Info: About to connect() to server1 port 4034 (#0)`
`== Info:   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx... == Info: connected`
`== Info: Connected to server1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 4034 (#0)`
`== Info: Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb`
`== Info:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`
`CApath: none`
`== Info: NSS error -5938`
`== Info: Closing connection #0`
`== Info: SSL connect error`
`curl: (35) SSL connect error`
I have installed the latest available version (7.46.0) that supports TLSv1.2.

There is any way to test it using curl? Or there is any way to debug the curl connection?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Disable server certificate verification, as suggested by shcherbak.
2. Do a full certificate validation, for this to work you should have root certificate of that CA, which was signed a certificate for your server. Put that certificate in  PEM form into some file, for example, ca.crt, and provide curl with additional command line argument: curl --cacert ca.crt

It is possible this will not work, from your messages I see your curl is built against NSS library, and that makes things slightly more complicated. NSS uses its own certificate storage. You could find files key3.db and cert8.db in Firefox profile - that's are NSS storages used by Firefox.

To manipulate those files there is certutil tool from Mozilla (maintainer of NSS library): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil . You should create cert8 (or cert9 if library has newer version) file, add your server certificate there as trusted and provide curl with that file. Where to put this file is indicated by SSL_DIR environment variable, default is /etc/pki/nssdb.

Read more on CURL security configuration here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have no Trusted CA for server you are trying to connect. Try to add -k (insecure option)

```
curl -k -v https://server1:4034/pages/Status.jsp --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both. Actually the new version of curl worked correctly, there was a firewall between the test server and the apache.
I had to install the new curl version on the apache server and it worked correctly.
Thank you very much everyone for your help.